# How to process invalid HTML documents from web with library which wants proper HTML

Tags: java, html, itext, saxparser

I am getting this error while parsing a web site .
ERROR:  'The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.'
or input type must b closed

Comment: 1: fix the input, 2 fix the library so that it can handle incorect html

Comment: Try [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), it can deal with brocken html.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [JTidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy/) ?

> JTidy is a Java port of HTML Tidy, a HTML syntax checker and pretty
>   printer. Like its non-Java cousin, JTidy can be used as a tool for
>   cleaning up malformed and faulty HTML. In addition, JTidy provides a
>   DOM parser for real-world HTML.

Obviously at some point it will struggle with the HTML depending on how badly-formed it is, but you may find this works for you.